# Why is the phrase "X votes" used for indicating a question's score?

Tags: discussion, design

It seems counter-intuitive to me that a question's score (on the question listing page) is labeled as "X votes"; I would assume that such a counter would indicate the *total number of votes*, not the value of a question after its combined upvote and downvote totals. This seems even stranger when a question has a negative score:

[image]

My automatic understanding of reading this is that the question has been voted upon -2 times, which is obviously not the case. Is there any reasoning behind this choice in wording as opposed to "X points" or another alternative?

Comment: Perhaps "-2 score"?

Comment: -2 (positive) votes -> n positive + (n+2) negative votes... Whether that really makes sense is left to the discretion of the reader.

Comment: Well, don't stop there.  "Answers" is nonsense, a question can't have two answers and none of them are actually an answer until the OP clicks the check-mark.  And "views" obviously has little to do with what you see when you open the curtains in the morning.  But then again, maybe they are just words that fit conveniently in the little box and nobody ever misunderstood what they really meant.

Comment: We should just remove labels altogether. No one can misinterpret a label that doesn't exist.

Comment: Even [post summary at Stack Design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/) uses this. Which I think it a mistake. I think it should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nQu3.png)